# RStudio keyboard shortcut to turn strings into objects and vice versa? (i.e. remove or add quotes around names)

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a keyboard shortcut for converting something like `rm("a", "b", "c", "d")` into `rm(a, b, c, d)`?

Comment: Is this specific for your implementation on `rm`?

Comment: @akrun no that's just an easy example

Comment: I would like to know the real (probably something that mimics) example, so that it becomes easier to know how you want to parameterize

Comment: @akrun ideally I want to be able to convert something some code that looks like `c("a", "b", "c")` into this `c(a, b, c)` (and vice-versa). Ideally with a keyboard shortcut (not a function that I have to type in and run). Ideally.

Comment: Note that symbols can be returned in a list.  I updated a function

Comment: You could make an addin, and set a shortkey to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an RStudio shortcut but you can do, *ctrl+F*, check the Regex box and replace `\"(.*?)\"` by `\1`

---

Coming back at it later, here are two functions that operate in both directions, 
You could build an addin from those and trigger the execution with hotkeys

```r
quote_vars <- function(expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  vars <- all.vars(expr)
  vars <- setNames(as.list(vars), vars)
  do.call(substitute, list(expr, vars))
}

unquote_strings <- function(expr) {
  expr <- deparse(substitute(expr))
  expr <- gsub("\"(.*?)\"", "\\1", expr)
  parse(text= expr)[[1]]
}

quote_vars(rm(a, b, c, d))
#> rm("a", "b", "c", "d")
unquote_strings(rm("a", "b", "c", "d"))
#> rm(a, b, c, d)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Would be interested to know (from yourself if anyone else) if it’s possible to go the other way around (eg from `a` to `”a”`)

Comment: @user5783745 you might be interested in the updated answer. If you have trouble with building an addin for those I think a new question would be the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

For viceversa conversions, an option is

```
f1 <- function(...) {

    v1 <- rlang::enexprs(...)
    if(is.character(v1[[1]])) {
        rlang::syms(v1)

    } else purrr::map(v1, ~ rlang::as_name(.x))
}
```

-testing

```
f1("a", "b", "c", "d") # changes to symbol
#[[1]]
#a

#[[2]]
#b

#[[3]]
#c

#[[4]]
#d


f1(a, b, c, d) # changes to character
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b"

#[[3]]
#[1] "c"

#[[4]]
#[1] "d"
```

NOTE: Returning a list to have consistent behavior

With `rm`, we can use `do.call`

```
out <- f1("a", "b", "c", "d")
do.call("rm", out)
```

```html
a
#Error: object 'a' not found
b
#Error: object 'b' not found
```

#### data

```
a <- b <- c <-d <- 1:5
```